# Can't get run my application after installing using NSIS script?

Tags: windows-services, nsis

I builded nsis script successfully for my java project. I have converted my java project into bat (windows machine requires bat file for executing) file named as `test.bat`. My installation steps done successfully.

After installation the bat file can not start the service. I have checked following path

```
Start Menu -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services.
```

I can see the services in this list, but i could not see my service file name.

I have tried following script lines

```
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$INSTDIR\test.bat"
```

Also i have tried this one

```
Function test
  ExecShell "" "$INSTDIR\test.bat"
FunctionEnd
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Is your application a service? Does your nsis installer register your application as a windows service? Windows services require a specific API set to be implemented. Also what do you mean by "converting the java project into bat"? Did you rename a .jar into .bat?

Comment: I dont know how to register my application as windows service.can you explain me?In my bat file contains classpath for all jar files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed a java service with the wrapper from http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org that is able to install jars as a service. IIRC you will need wrapper.exe, wrapper.dll, and wrapper.jar to be installed along your application. Check the website for further information.

Then you have NSIS call that wrapper to install the service on the target machine:

```
Detailprint "Installing service"
nsExec::Exec "$\"$INSTDIR\wrapper.exe$\" -i $\"$INSTDIR\wrapper.conf$\""
```

The uninstaller portion:

```
Detailprint "Stopping service"
nsExec::Exec "$\"$INSTDIR\wrapper.exe$\" -p $\"$INSTDIR\wrapper.conf$\""

Detailprint "Removing service"
nsExec::Exec "$\"$INSTDIR\wrapper.exe$\" -r $\"$INSTDIR\wrapper.conf$\""
```

As you can see, you will also have to create a wrapper.conf to specify details about the service (e.g. which main class to use). After installing the service you should be able to start it with something like...

```
Exec '"net start your_service_name"'
```